# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found Symfony 3

Tags: symfony

I encounter a problem on my application, I have the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ws.T_GP' doesn't exist
```

With the local server the application works perfectly, but as soon as I use the online server, the error appears.

The local server is however identical to the online server.
Databases are also the same.

The table exists in the database, but the error remains.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: try php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force , php app/console cache:clear 
... and confirme that you already have an Entity called "T_GP"

Comment: It is possible to do this with an online database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely a case issue. Are you sure that the table is called `T_GP` and not `t_gp`?
I had the same problem one day and it was just because of the characters.

You should configure doctrine to use lower case table name. Refer to the doctrine documentation http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#persistent-classes to know how to do so.

I hope it will help you :)

Comment: Ow ! Ow! It works, it was a problem of capitalization in the name of my table :D Thank you very much !!!!